# How to check if a value is within a range of values in Spotfire

Tags: range, filtering, numeric, calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a set of ranges for specific values, for example I attached a table. [ID Ranges to filter out specific IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIOit.png) The idea of this table is to specify which values are "included" / falls within the range, and which not. Since it's too much time consuming filtering out every specific number, it is maintained this way.

In my main dataset I have a column called "ID" and would like to check if it is categorized as included or not included (filtered out) based on whether the ID falls inside of a range in that table.

If ID = 11 , it means this row/record is labeled as not included.

The desired outcome for this is: [desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzxas.png)

I tried looking at the binned functions but failed on getting a solution. Is there perhaps a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a calculated column that (if your ranges were immutable) would look something like this (if your table had ranges 2-10, 12-15 and 30-34 for example).

```
case  
when ([ID]>=2) and ([ID]<=10) then 'T' 
when ([ID]>=12) and ([ID]<=15) then 'T' 
when ([ID]>=30) and ([ID]<=34) then 'T'
else 'F' end
```

Instead of trying to do complex/slow joins, you could write an IronPython script that takes the table of ranges and produces a document property that contains exactly this expression, but you don't need to re-type it when the ranges change, just remember to re-run the script.

The document property, in this case called 'checkValid' can be used to calculate the [T/F] column by simply assigning ${checkValid} as the column expression in the expression editor.

The script is below: the document property needs to be created before running the script; the script needs re-running every time the ranges table (here called 'table') changes. You could e.g. add it to a button in a text area.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

#data table with the ranges
table=Document.Data.Tables["table"]

#add data cursors to Min and Max columns
cursor1 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(table.Columns["Min"])
cursor2 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(table.Columns["Max"])

#initialize list
expr_vector = []
#loop through table and create 'when...' strings
for row in table.GetRows(cursor1,cursor2):
    low = cursor1.CurrentValue
    high = cursor2.CurrentValue
    value = 'when [ID]>='+low+' and [ID]<='+high+' then "T"'
    expr_vector.Add(value)
    
#collapse vector to string
expr=' '.join(expr_vector)
#add prefix and suffix to form complete expression
expr='CASE '+expr+' else "F" end'

#store in a document property
Document.Properties["checkValid"] = expr
```